# In bootstrap 4 how to get a row or column to expand to full height within the parent container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Trying to get a row (article tags) to go to the bottom of the parent container.  Basic layout looks like this:

```
<div class='row mb-3'>
    <div class='col-3'> [ thumbnail image goes here ]</div>
    <div class="col-9'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-12>Article title</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-12>Article excerpt</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-12>Tags: tag1, tag2, tag3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The excerpt row will have varying amounts of text in it.  How can I get the tags row to be at the bottom of the col-9 column?[image]

@Zim's answer below seems to get close, but the middle column that should expand to the height of the parent container (row with thumbnail image) goes full page height instead:

[image]

The tags row is down at the bottom of the page window.  With multiple rows being output the tags row is way down in the next row's content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use `min-vh-100` and `flex-column` on the parent row
2. Use `flex-grow-1` to fill the height

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"> [ thumbnail image goes here ]</div>
        <div class="col-9">
            <div class="row flex-column min-vh-100">
                <div class="col-12">Tags: tag1, tag2, tag3</div>
                <div class="col-12 flex-fill">Article title</div>
                <div class="col-12">Article excerpt</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***EDIT***

Based on the comments, to grow in height of the adjacent column instead of viewport height...

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 bg-warning">
            [img]
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
            <div class="row flex-column h-100">
                <div class="col flex-grow-0">Tags: tag1, tag2, tag3</div>
                <div class="col flex-fill bg-success">Article title</div>
                <div class="col flex-grow-0">Article excerpt</div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/Ft0l3NPena)

Comment: This is close I think - see my added info in the main question.  That flex-fill breaks out of the first row (row mb-3).  So if my thumbnail is say 300px high, that flex-fill pushes that content down to the bottom of the page, overlapping the next row.

Comment: Why are you using `mb-3`?

Comment: the mb-3 was just to give some vertical spacing between the main row - each article has a row, 3 cols for thumbnail, 9 columns for info - title, excerpt and tags.  If the thumbnail works out to 250px high, I don't want the col-9 to be taller than the col-3.